# Using is_numeric in shorthand coding in checking the variable if it is a string or numeric

Tags: php, ternary-operator

Having a hard time trying to figure out how I can use ternary operations in trying to determine if the value of a variable inside is a number/integer or a string. If it is a number it will display the `$score` with text or words inside. If it is a `text or string` it will only show the value. Having a

```
$score = 42

$variables['page']['sidebar_first']['block_scored']['#markup'] = '<div id="entry-score"><h3><span>' . (is_numeric($score)) . '</span></h3></div>';
```

Comment: No ternary operator here.

Comment: Sorry  what I meant to say is using short hand code

Comment: Where's your ternary?

Comment: @clestcruz that is not a shorthand code either, its a plain variable and you're trying to concatenate it with the result of your is_numeric.

Comment: @prix apologies for my ignorance, was trying to look for a way to compress or reduce my if else condition to something shorter that is why I thought it was shorthand

Comment: @clestcruz your question is a bit hard to understand, so basically you want that **if** `$score` is a number, it shows the number it holds, otherwise it prints a custom message? If so, this answer to your question should be all u need https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701659/342740 you just need to replace `'number'` with `$score` and use `$result` where you have `(is_numeric($score))` in your current code.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing a ternary:

`(is_numeric($score) ? $score : null)`

Answer (score 2):

At the current time, you are displaying either true, if `$score` is a number or false, if it is not and are not using the ternary operator.

The ternary operator is quite simple to use:

```
$result = (is_numeric($score)) ? 'number' : 'not a number';
```

Now `$result` will contain either the word 'number' if it is one or 'not a number' if it is a string or just something other then a number.

I don't fully understand your question, so please, update what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function do_output($score)
{
    $format = ['%s', 'Your score is: %d'];
    printf($format[is_numeric($score)], $score);
}

do_output(42);
do_output('Some text that is not a number.');
```

Output:

```
Your score is: 42Some text that is not a number.
```

String assignment:

```
$output = sprintf(['<p>%s</p>', 'Your score is: <b>%d</b>'][is_numeric($score)], $score);
```

As you can see no ternary is required here.  is_numeric is used to determine the index of the array containing output formats for s/printf.

Or with a ternary:

```
$output = is_numeric($score)
    ? 'Your score is: <b>' . $score . '</b>'
    : '<p>' . $score . '</p>';
```

Comment: Not a good idea, the first suggestion: is_numeric returns a boolean which you should not be using as array key. The suggestion to use a ternary condition is more appropriate.

Comment: It's a matter of taste.  If you don't like the type juggling you can simply cast the result of is_numeric to an int.

Comment: Sure, you can cast the value before using it as array key. A condition is still more legible though. The dynamic array key trick is usually pretty good but it doesn't make much sense when you're working with a boolean - that is *exactly* why we have conditions in the first place. And ternary syntax to condense it, space wise.